# How to make custom ribbon on existing workbook using VBA and without downloading other software?

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:**

I would like to be able to edit the ribbon on a single workbook and place my own tabs and macros within the custom ribbon. Obviously I don't these tabs to show on other workbooks etc (there are few rules, see below section)...

**Rules**

1. Ideally I want to be able to do it without downloading anything. My work place is crazy strict with downloading from the outside world. (but I might be able to do it fromm home if its the best way).
2. I need to be able to do it on an existing workbook, there are just to many graphs/formatting/data/macros within the workbook to move everything over to a new workbook.
3. Ideally it needs to be a very repeatable/Safe/Reliable method, this workbook is a massive work in progress so I will probably be coming back to it and adding more tabs/macros as the months go by.

**Previous attempts**

I have tried working with the custom UI briefly in the past. People suggested things like downloading the custom UI editor? I think that I managed to sort of start editing an existing sheet that had the custom UI within it already. But I could not figure out how to increment this into an existing workbook very easily.

FYI I am very familiar with VBA but not HTML...

Can anyone give me a few quick steps that I need to do or is there some documentation out there? I did try looking but couldn't find anything....

Cheers

Comment: Only possible with the *custom UI editor*, and yes it is not easy but it works. There is no way to do this with VBA.

Comment: You will need to change the file extension to `.zip` and add/edit a few files. Once done, you will need to change it back to .xlsx for testing etc. Much easier with the custom UI editor. See this and don't forget to backup your file, a lot of things can go wrong. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/customize-the-office-fluent-ribbon-by-using-an-open-xml-formats-file

Comment: I might just have to download the custom UI editor and do it at home :/. You would have thought microsoft would make it a lot easier to do...

Comment: I have followed the instructions from Kostas above answer nad it works like a charm... It is actaully very easy to do this way